# Meteor iron:router transitions

Tags: javascript, meteor, css-transitions

I am trying to implement transitions between pages by using iron:router. I defined the animations in the css and now everything I need is to call them with the iron:router. For some reason the following code:

```
animateContentOut = function() {
    $('#content').removeClass("animated fadeIn");
    return $('footer').addClass("hide");
}

fadeContentIn = function() {
    $('#content').addClass("animated fadeIn");
    return $('footer').removeClass("hide");
}

Router.onBeforeAction(animateContentOut);
Router.onAfterAction(fadeContentIn);
```

returns an exception:

> Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in
>   an onBeforeAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the Iron-Router documentation, now both `onBeforeAction` and `onAfterAction` callbacks require `this.next()`. https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router

So simply simply add that line to the end of your `fadeContentIn` and `animateContentOut` code.

Comment: I updated my code so now it works perfectly. But the only problem is that it works only in the first route.

Comment: had you also done it for `animateContentOut`? I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have login try like this

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      this.render('Login');
    } else { 
      this.next();
     }
});
```